# Remove null values from javascript array

Tags: javascript, null

I am having a javascript array.

```
addresses = new Array(document.client.cli_Build.value, 
    document.client.cli_Address.value, 
    document.client.cli_City.value, 
    document.client.cli_State.value, 
    document.client.cli_Postcode.value, 
    document.client.cli_Country.value);
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = addresses.join(", ");
```

I have to copy the content of all these array value to the postal address textarea. when i use the above join function, comma has been added for null values. How to remove this extra commas?

Thanks

Answer (score 52):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the *null* values:

```
addresses.filter(function(val) { return val !== null; }).join(", ")
```

Comment: Like this better than post processing the joined array elements.

Comment: is there a `filter` in every javascript? I think there is not in some IE

Comment: For the record, I like it better too :), and would do it like that with the help of Underscore.js

Comment: I think you are right, filter is not available in all IE versions.

Comment: @Victor: No, `filter` was specified first in ECMAScript 5 (December 2009). But most modern browsers do have that implemented.

Comment: @Victor: A workaround would be either to define that method if missing or using a simple `for` loop to filter the elements out.

Comment: @Gumbo: And what for the poor users stuck with a non-modern browser, like IE8?

Comment: @Victor: See my previous comment.

Comment: @Gumbo: Dress it any way you want, this code is not useful. Would you always post `undefinedFunction()` as a solution, to then tell people to just "define the method"? That is not very helpful...

Comment: you don't even need the val !== null, since returning null evaluates to false, use can just "return val;"

Comment: @chrismarx So does `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, and `""`.

Comment: @chrismarx What I meant it that `[null,undefined,"",0,NaN].filter(function(val) { return val; })` returns an empty array and not just `[undefined,"",0,NaN]`. However, `function(val) { return val !== null; }` does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, is true, and those are likely also things I want removed from my array, but worth pointing out-

Comment: @chrismarx Maybe you, but maybe not Krishna Priya.

Comment: A better version: `addresses.filter(val => { return !!val }).join(', ')`

Comment: @Justin I prefer `Boolean(val)` over `!!val` - which then has the really nice effect that you can use `addresses.filter(Boolean).join(', ')` as the [current second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52529695/327074)

Answer (score 12):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to remove all [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values:

```js
var list = [null, undefined, 0, 1, 2, '', 'test'];

// ES5:
var result = list.filter(Boolean).join(', ');
console.log(result);

// ES6, saves 3 characters:
var result = list.filter(x => x).join(', ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `filter(Boolean)` removes all the falsy values, so if you want to keep `0` you have to pass it as `'0'`.

Comment: I actually prefer the ES5 version because its clearer what your intention is - I only knew about the ES6 version, so thanks for teaching me the old skool ways :)

Comment: I think the ES5 version is obtuse and not clear at all. I would read it as "filter booleans" - I actually have to think, "Oh, Boolean is a constructor that takes an initial value as a parameter, so this is passing the array values into that constructor". I find myself hoping that the constructor doesn't take any more parameters.
It doesn't read well at all, imo.

Answer (score 6):

Another filter alternative

```
myArray.filter(function(val){if(val)return val}).join(", ")
```

```js
document.write(['this','','',,,,'is','a',,,'test'].filter(function(val){if(val)return val}).join(", "));
```

Answer (score 5):

[Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is a nice utility library for functional programming and list manipulation:

```
_.filter(addresses, function(val) { return val !== null; }).join(", ");
```

Edit: And there is a more compact way (Thanks Andrew De Andrade!):

```
_.compact(addresses).join(", ");
```

Comment: _.compact() performs a filter that removes falsy values: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#compact

Answer (score 1):

addresses.filter(Boolean).join(", ")

Answer (score 0):

```
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = 
    document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value.replace(/(, )+/g,", ");
```

Or should it be

```
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = 
    document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value
    .replace(/(null, )/g,"").replace(/(, null)/g,"");
```

??

Comment: add a "g" to do multiple search and replace.

Comment: this code works like a charm .Thanks for quick reply.

document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value=document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value.replace(/(, )+/g,", ");

But i am getting a comma added at the end of the address

Comment: /*Remove null values*/
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value=document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value.replace(/(, )+/g,", ");
/* Remove last comma */
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value.slice(0, -2); 
/*Remove first comma*/
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value.substr(1); 

I used these codes and working fine now. thank u so much for ur help

Answer (score 0):

One could also use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

It *reduces* an array to a single value, e.g. a string. Like so:

```
addresses.reduce(function (a, b) {
        if (a && b) { return a + ', ' + b; }
        if (a) { return a; }
        return b;
      }, '');
```

`a` holds the intermediate result,
`b` holds the current element.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to eliminate all the undefined, null, NaN, "", 0, a simple way to do it is to use a combination of filter call back function and boolean function.

```
var filterArr=arr.filter(function(val){
   return Boolean(val);  
  });
```

When you pass a value to the boolean function, if the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false.

Here is an example of this usage:

```
 function bouncer(arr) {

         var filterArr=arr.filter(function(val){
           return Boolean(val);  
          });

      return filterArr;
    }
```

Here are some tests:

```
bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);//should return [1, 2]
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);// should return [7, "ate", 9]
bouncer(["a", "b", "c"]);// should return ["a", "b", "c"]
bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);//should return []
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove the `null` values only, its short & simple:

```
addresses = addresses.filter(n => (n===null) ? false : true).join(', ');
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = addresses;
```

If you want to remove `null`, `0`, `false` & `""`(Empty String) like values, then use this:

```
document.client.cli_PostalAddress.value = addresses.filter(Boolean).join(', ');
```