# null values issue of an array in a function like counting sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, counting

I am writing a function that orders numbers inserting them in an other support array in the positions that have the same value of the numbers.After that i scan all the support array and i insert all sorted numbers in the originary array in successive position.In this way i can order the numbers but a lot of positions of the support array result to have null values and scanning It i have a longer cycle of for.How  can i eliminate all null values before scanning support array?Does exists a way for this function that permit to scan only position that heven't null value?I have thought for a solution but i didn't manage to find It.

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate null values"? Do you mean how to prevent the use of conditions to check if an array element is null while scanning through the array?

Comment: No,i Mean to eliminate null values of the array.For example: [null,1] becomes  [1].Or find a method to scan only the positions of the array that are different from null.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: In general, [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Example: [Remove null values from javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132030/remove-null-values-from-javascript-array)

Comment: You can also avoid the need for `.filter()` by using [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: With filter function the support array Will be scanned one time more (one to remove null values and one to insert sorted values in principal array)and It is not great.I wanted to know some methods without using default functions of javascript.

Comment: Or better,reproducing them

Comment: Please post your code.