# Javascript: Conditionally add objects to array in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my JS code I have two booleans, `flag1` and `flag2`. I want to create an array `['a', 'b', 'c']` where `a` is included only if `flag1` is true, and where `b` is included only if `flag2` is true. What I have now is `[flag1 ? 'a' : null, 'b', flag2 ? 'c' : null]`, but if `flag1` and `flag2` are false this gives me `[null, 'b', null]` instead of `['b']`.

SOLUTION:

Here's the cleanest way I found for doing it: `[...(flag1 ? ['a'] : []),'b',...(flag2 ? ['c'] : [])]`

Comment: [flag1 ? 'a' : null, 'b', flag2 ? 'c' : null].filter(x=>x!==null)?

Comment: its seems duplicate of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132030/remove-null-values-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function which returns either the value inside an array or an empty array for spreading into an array.

```js
const
    either = (condition, value) => condition ? [value] : [],
    getArray = (flag1, flag2) => [
        ...either(flag1, 'a'),
        ...either(flag2, 'b'),
        'c'
    ];
    
console.log(...getArray(true, true));
console.log(...getArray(false, true));
console.log(...getArray(true, false));
console.log(...getArray(false, false));
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thanks, this works! See my update to original question to see the way I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Another one implementation:

```js
const flag1 = true;
const flag2 = false;
const data = [[flag1, 'a'], [flag2, 'b'], [true, 'c']];

const result = data.flatMap(([flag, letter]) => flag ? letter : []);

console.log(result);
```